# How to avoid request of all images used for different devices using media query?

Tags: css, page-speed, responsive-webdesign, asp.net-mvc, media-queries

I want to know, how can I avoid loading all images I created for different devices using media query. Currently my mark up look like below :

```
    <img src="/media/1062/lg.png" alt="Fresh from garden" class="visible-lg">
    <img src="/media/1062/lg.png" alt="Fresh from garden" class="visible-md">
    <img src="/media/1062/lg.png" alt="Fresh from garden" class="visible-sm">
    <img src="/media/1062/lg.png" alt="Fresh from garden" class="visible-xs">
```

above loads all images irrespective of device and makes page heavier for mobile devices.
I'm using razor cshtml and looking for best way to implement this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65719/mobile-browsers-do-they-ignore-noscriptimg-responsive-design-with-framew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use CSS based media queries in any case because browsers will download all those images regardless if they are being shown or hidden. You can achieve what you want using either HTML5 markup or Javascript.

*Here is just a few methods that should get you started:*

- [Img Srcset (HTML5 Markup)](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#example-29489991)

  - `<img sizes="100vw" srcset="sm.jpg 400w, md.jpg 800w, lg.jpg 1600w" src="sm.jpg">`
- [Picture (HTML5 Markup)](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#example-ed8956bf)

  - `<picture>
       <source media="(min-width: 36em)" srcset="lg.jpg 1024w, md.jpg 640w, sm.jpg 320w" sizes="33.3vw">
       <source srcset="cropped-lg.jpg 2x, cropped-sm.jpg 1x" />
       <img src="sm.jpg" />
    </picture>`
- [Zurb Foundation Interchange (JavaScript)](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/interchange.html)

  - `<img data-interchange="[sm.jpg, small], [md.jpg, medium], [lg.jpg, large]">`
- [Koen Vendrik's Responsive Images (JavaScript)](https://github.com/kvendrik/responsive-images.js)

  - `<img data-src-base='/' data-src='<480:xs.jpg,<768:sm.jpg,<960:md.jpg,>960:lg.jpg'>`
- [ResponsiveJS (JavaScript)](http://responsejs.com/#sets)

  - `<img src="sm.png" data-min-device-width-641="md.png">`
- [Responsive Img (JavaScript)](http://responsiveimg.com/)

  - `<img id="img1" src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" />`
- [lazySizes (JavaScript)](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/)

  - `<img sizes="(min-width:1000px) 930px, 90vw" data-srcset="sm.jpg 500w, md.jpg 640w, lg.jpg 1024w" data-src="md.jpg" class="lazyload">`
- [ImagerJS (JavaScript) Kinda old but still works](https://github.com/BBC-News/Imager.js/)

  - `<div class="delayed-image-load" data-src="example{width}" data-alt="text"></div>`

Comment: Actually media queries work perfectly fine for background images, see https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat background images are YUK for actual page content, not only do they not count as page content by search engines they can unnecessary bloat your code if your using them for page content on many pages. The methods listed are intended for page content, not surrounding template elements. Generally a website would want to use `<div>` or another similar tag for a background not `<img>`. Back in 2012, we didn't have SRCSET :)

Comment: @SimonHayter, what should be best way out of all your suggestions?

Comment: @Sangeeta Srcset or Zurb Interchange. Personally I prefer Zurb because it has minimal markup and easier to use that srcset.

Comment: @Sangeeta You could use Zurb Interchange div, see jsfiddle I made here for you: https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/7a8ba66k/

Comment: @SimonHayter When I analyzed both it comes out that both loads all images irrespective of device consuming bandwidth defeating the very purpose of saving bandwidth and faster page load.

Can some one suggest me, which way I can only load images that is required for specific device and avoid loading all images when page loads?

Comment: You analysed wrong. The JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/7a8ba66k/ uses a different method. The noscript will always download, this is a fallback... so at most you will have two download... if you don't want a fallback remove it.

Comment: Hi @SimonHayter, Can you clarify one most important thing about Srcset and Zurb that does it start by requesting all images and then displaying the best one or just requesting best one and later downloading rest of the image set in background? My primary concern is web page speed.

Comment: `SRC=""` will always download regardless... its the options that do not unless the viewpoint triggers them... meaning you should at most have two downloads instead of all.